# Why would an artist avoid the Pen Tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape

I am going through some vector tutorials using Inkscape. Part of the author's description of himself states: "I spend most of my time working in Adobe Illustrator, avoiding the Pen Tool and struggling to find the perfect colors."

I have found that this artist's/author's tutorials are helpful. I haven't worked with vector graphics in awhile. The tutorials are interesting; and, the artist's/author's projects produce cool artwork.

Does anyone else out there avoid the pen tool?

I did send the author a message to see what he has to say.

Here are links to this artist's/author's tutorials and web pages:

http://vforvectors.com/

http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-propeller-pinwheel-illustration-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-21465

(Does anyone know Andrei Marius? I made sure that I told him in my message that I did like his work and enjoyed his tutorials.)

Comment: We can't possibly answer the question of why someone does what they do. You have to ask them. As for other people's personal answers, they'd be mostly opinion. I don't think this is a good fit for this site.

Comment: Purely my opinion: the pen tool is hard to master for a lot of people. Working with bezier curves and handles doesn't come naturally to everyone, and it can takes years of practice to feel comfortable with knowing how to get the quality-looking results you want quickly. I've been using Illustrator every day for nearly 15 years and I don't necessarily look forward to using it when I need to.

Comment: If all the artwork you are creating is based upon geometric shapes, then there's often no need for the pen tool. The Pen tool is most helpful when you are creating freeform objects that can't easily be created by altering a polygon.

Comment: I agree with @Scott. If you can do something in 3 seconds with perfect symmetry instead of spending 2 minutes on that shape, that makes sense to simply not use the pen tool. In that sense, a lot of us do like the author of the tutorials!

Comment: Well.. I don't *avoid* the Pen Tool by any means. But it does have it's place. It's silly to use the Pen Tool to draw a circle, even though you can :)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I agree that the Pen Tool is just that: a tool to be used when it is appropriate. I was lucky to have my first instructor (a successful graphic artist) teach my class how to use this tool right off the bat. We used it for both Illustrator and Photoshop. So, we weren't frustrated by it at all. I think, as beginners to the applications, we trusted out teacher and followed her example. But, I can see how someone can be frustrated with it. When I learned to use Inkscape I had to learn different keystrokes. I was a bit awkward with it.

Comment: I did receive a nice message from the artist/author of the tutorials. He said that he was self-taught and hated that Pen Tool because he just couldn't get the hang of it. So, he approached Illustrator from a different angle: he tried to do as much as possible without the Pen Tool. But, he has since learned to use it well enough where he feels...well...he doesn't hate it any more. LOL

Answer (score 1):

**This is more of a long comment**

There are quite a lot of times I do not use pen tool. If you draw geometric shapes its often unnecessary to work with the pen tool. To give you an arbitrary example of picture with no need to use the pen tool consider the one below:

[image: Isometric]

**Image 1**: Image only has lines (original [purpose for image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/isometric/info))

There is no need to use the pen tool, the image is intentionally simple to drive home this point. The line tool will work just fine. I can always unite the shapes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, or shape builder <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. The line tool has several advantages over the pen tool in making straight lines.

Do I avoid the pen tool. Certainly not. There are a lot of shapes that can not be done without it. It is just not the tool for everything.

[image]

**Image 2**: Similar image that can be done without using pen tool, now with color fill and curvature to show what can easily be achieved without using pen tool.

### However

The pinwheel tutorial you link seems like a situation where i would consider using pen tool, although i could certainly do it using direct selection tool after I've instructed illustrator to make tangents for my segments.

Seems a bit excessive amount of work for the effect. On the other hand, having it done like this makes it easier to follow in the tutorial for more or less exactly the same look. But YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, joojaa. I appreciate the explanation of how you accomplish things using different tools. And, I just realized that I avoid the Line Tool when I probably should be using it. I use the Pen because I am just used to selecting it from the menu.

Comment: @rt.hawk well i never really had any problems although I would be more happy drawing rational b-splines by control points.